# Is $(11)$ a prime ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

Is $(11)$ a prime ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$? I know that $11$ is an irreducible element in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$. Now to determine whether it is prime we can say $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2 + 5)$. So we get an isomorphism
$$ 
\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]/(11) \;\;\simeq\;\; \mathbb{Z}_{11}[x]/(x^2 + 5)
\,.$$

Since $\mathbb{Z}_{11}$ is a field, $\mathbb{Z}_{11}[x]$ is a PID, and since $(x^2 + 5)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}_{11}[x]$, the ring $\mathbb{Z}_{11}[x]/(x^2 + 5)$ is a field. Hence $(11)$ can be treated as a maximal ideal as well as a prime ideal in the ring $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$.

Comment: Your method is correct and answer too. Refer this [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1166143/show-that-langle-13-rangle-is-a-prime-ideal-in-mathbbz-sqrt-5?rq=1) for more methods.

Answer (score 3):

As indicated in the comments, yes, you are correct. It might be wise to justify why $(x^2+5)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}_{11}[x]$ though.

---

<sup>I'm posting this CW answer so that users who **confidently** concur have something to vote on, and so this question doesn't stagnate in the [Unanswered Questions Queue](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=unanswered). If however anyone would like to write a more substantial response to the question, please downvote this answer and post your response.</sup>