# Searching for two primes that are prime in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ and two primes that aren't prime in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I'm currently interested in finding prime numbers $p > 7$ that are / aren't prime in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$.I tried to mod out any prime I'm interested in and see if $$\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}] / (p)$$ has no zero divisors, but that I can't seem to find any.

I also tried to find some product xy, s.t. $p \mid xy$ but $p \nmid x$ and $p \nmid y$ (which I would show using the Norm) but finding such a product is also pretty difficult.

Has anyone have a clue how to approach this? Is there a general formula for primes / non-primes in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$

Comment: Hint: what can you say about the norm of a prime in that ring?

Comment: This can be answered by quadratic reciprocity. So $(p)=(2),(3)$ is not prime, but $p=(11), (13)$ is prime. See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2120415/is-11-a-prime-ideal-of-mathbbz-sqrt-5?noredirect=1&lq=1).